# How to create mass CASE statement on table

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have the table as defined below (that is output by a view). As can be seen, there are many values as -0.01 that are just noise to the user.

Given there are 48 columns, creating 48 seperate CASE statemnts would yield very slow results.

Can a *mass* case be used to clean up this data, ie:

```
  select 
      CASE
      WHEN * = -0.01
        THEN 0
      ELSE *
      END
  from aTable
```

*Data:*

[image]

Comment: That's a really bad way to store data... That's way you have this odd problem.

Comment: @jarlh The data must be stored this way as the software that accepts it will ignore if the value is -0.01, btu now we need the data for reporting purposes...

Comment: No, it can't.  And, 48 `case` statements probably would not noticeably slow down the query.

Comment: @Sauron: I suppose jarlh refers to your database design. A new month should add data to a table, not change its structure.

Comment: You could start with an UNPIVOT, use a single CASE statement, and then re-PIVOT.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner We have a rolling time horizon, so every once in a while the table structure will be updated, (it is a third party vendor software, not well thought out but I am stuck with it....)

Comment: How about an ETL (Extract, Transform and Load) job/script to load the data into some reporting tables (created and maintained by you). These could have a normalized design and you could then query and pivot on them the way others have suggested

Comment: Have you actually tried 48 statements and shown that it is slow?? Even if SQL did what you wanted (it doesn't), behind the scenes 48 comparisons would *still* be performed....

Comment: if the valid values are all whole numbers without decimals you could use `CONVERT(INT, [field])` and that will make the -0.01 = 0

Comment: @NWest i have inputted the 48 CASES, no real performance reduction, still executes in 1 sec. I posted the question as curiousity if there was  a unique way to mass update the columns

Comment: @user1221684 That is perfect, it's faster and more succinct than the CASES, (exec is 0 sec vs 1 sec), thanks, accepting answer

Comment: @user1221684 If you want to write it up, I can accept the answer as correct

Answer (score 2):

If your concern is the time it takes to write the code, you could use Dynamic SQL to help write it for you by referencing the sys tables:

```
    SELECT 'CASE WHEN ' + columns.NAME + ' = -.01 THEN 0 ELSE ' 
+ columns.NAME + ' END AS ' + columns.NAME + ', ' AS Dynamic_SQL
    FROM sys.columns
    INNER JOIN sys.objects ON objects.object_id = columns.object_id
    WHERE objects.NAME = 'aTable'
    ORDER BY column_id
```